# Create object of extended type

Tags: java, extends

I have a class looking like this:

```
public class MyClass1 extends MyClass2 {
  ...
}
```

Now I have an object of MyClass2 and would like to create an Object of type MyClass1. How can this be done? The following is not a very nice way to do it:

```
MyClass2 origin = new MyClass2();
MyClass1 goal = new MyClass1();
goal.var1 = origin.var1;
goal.var2 = origin.var2;
goal.var3 = origin.var3;
```

And this way dose not work but feels to be in the right direction?

```
public MyClass2(MyClass2 copy){
  this = copy;
}

public MyClass1(MyClass2 copy){
  super(copy);
}
```

Comment: you know that MyClass1 is basically MyClass2 but in most cases with some more fields?

Comment: Are you just looking to cast it? `MyClass1 goal = origin` ? Or did you want to do a deep copy?

Comment: You can create an instance :  `MyClass1 obj1 = new MyClass1();` or `MyClass2 obj2 = new MyClass1();` if you need something else, can you provide more details ?

Comment: `MyClass1` is `MyClass2`, and can be directly casted, but vice-versa does not stand. So, `MyClass2` is not `MyClass1`. You need to use copy constructor or similar approach to create `MyClass1` out of `MyClass2` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a copy constructor, which is similar to what you attempted :

In the sub-class:

```
public MyClass1 (MyClass2 source) {
    super (source);
}
```

In the base-class:

```
public MyClass2 (MyClass2 source) {
    this.var1 = source.var1;
    this.var2 = source.var2;
    this.var3 = source.var3;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Problem here is that MyClass2 is complex and the list of varX would be long. It feels like it should be some way to do a copy of the object instead?

Comment: @Grains I think the only other way would be to use the reflection API... you may just want to get busy writing those individual field assignments instead ;-)

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thanks. But in that case an better approach would be to remove "extends" and have the "MyClass2" as an variable instead. A bit sad but at least I can have a copy of the object that way.

Comment: Not happy with the solution but I finally did it this way.